# Lambda function for renaming a file (based on last modified) from an S3 bucket and copy it to another S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have this weird scenario where our internal service won't process a file fully, so we are stuck in this loop where:

1. A file gets created in a S3 bucket folder (Source bucket)
2. We need to download the file onto local Desktop
3. Rename the file
4. Upload the file to another Destination S3 Bucket folder

And repeat the same for like 30 times. It's been super pain to handle. But I know Lambda can automate some portion of it.

I got to the lambda for copying the file from source to destination (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-copy-s3-files/), but the renaming logic of renaming the file is missing.

Can anyone shed some knowledge on this rookie.

Cheers!

Copy a file from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket by renaming the file.

Comment: Replace the `key` in the `copy(source, destination_bucket, key)` line with the value you want the new object to be.  If you have a specific question on how to do this, please show what you've tried so far, and what the renaming rules should be.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure the AWS Lambda function to trigger when a new object is created in the Amazon S3 bucket.

The Lambda function can then copy the object and 'rename' at the same time:

```py
import boto3
import urllib

TARGET_BUCKET = 'my-target-bucket'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get incoming bucket and key
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    source_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    # Add 'rename' functionality here
    target_key = ??

    # Copy object to different bucket
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': source_bucket,
        'Key': source_key
    }
    s3_resource.Bucket(TARGET_BUCKET).Object(target_key).copy(copy_source)
```